# Is it possible for one device to subscribe to MQTT events or commands from another device on IBM IoTF?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, node-red

I am building an iOS app to control my Raspberry Pi over MQTT. I want to be able to send control commands from my iPhone to the Pi and have the Pi respond with a status update.

The Pi is running Node-RED and can both send and receive both events and commands to IBM IoT Foundation (verified from a Bluemix Node-RED application).

The iPhone Swift app is using https://cocoapods.org/pods/MQTTClient (Note - does not specifically list IBM IoT as a tested platform).

From the Swift app, I have successfully connected to IBM IoTF and sent **events** which the Pi receives.  I have also successfully subscribed to command topics in the form `"iot-2/cmd/streamStarted/fmt/json"`, but never receive a message.  If I try to publish a command in the form `"iot-2/cmd/startStream/fmt/json"` or subscribe to events in the form `"iot-2/evt/streamStarted/fmt/json"` or `"iot-2/type/myPi/id/<myPiID>/evt/streamStarted/fmt/json"`, the connection immediately closes.

The bottom line is that I need to get a status message from the Pi to the iPhone in some way.  I don't really care if it is an event, a command or something else.  I have been successful doing this with `test.mosquitto.org`, events but not IoT Foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only applications can send commands to a device.  You can't send a command from one device to another.  Is the iphone swift app connecting to IoT Foundation as an application or trying to connect as a device?

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting my head on straight.  :-)  Yes, I flipped it around so the iPhone app connects as an app and things work the way I wanted - iPhone sends commands to Pi, Pi sends events to iPhone.  Thanks!